# How to filter queryset by string field containing json (Django + SQLite)

Tags: django

I have the following situation.
The Flight model (flights) has a field named 'airlines_codes' (TextField) in which I store data in JSON array like format:

```
["TB", "IR", "EP", "XX"]
```

I need to filter the flights by 2-letter airline code (IATA format), for example 'XX', and I achieve this primitively but successfully like this:

```
filtered_flights = Flight.objects.filter(airlines_codes__icontains='XX')
```

This is great but actually not.
I have flights where airlines_codes look like this:

```
["TBZ", "IR", "EP", "XXY"]
```

Here there are 3-letter codes (ICAO format) and obviously the query filter above will not work.

PS. I cannot move to PostgreSQL, also I cannot alter in anyway the database. This has to be achieved only by some query.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: have you tried `filtered_flights = Flight.objects.filter(airlines_codes__icontains='XX')` ?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, my post was not correct, I have now corrected. Yes this is what i have tried and it works if codes in json like text field are 2 letter. And obviously when there are 3 letter codes - it will not give correct results. I need just the 2-letter coded airline.

Comment: Can you put some example for the output that you wanna get?

Comment: This is working solution that gives correct result https://stackoverflow.com/a/72116139/18977467 I do not think there is smth better in my situation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without altering the database in any way you need to filter the value as a string. Your best bet might be [`airlines_codes__contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains-1). Here's what I would recommend assuming your list will always be cleaned exactly as you represent it.

```py
Flight.objects.filter(airlines_codes__contains='"XX"')
```

As of Django 3.1 [`JSONField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) is supported on a wider array of databases. Ideally, for someone else building a similar system from the ground up, this field would be a preferable approach.

Comment: :) I am quite upset I could not figure out such simple solution. Just had to play with strings.
Only that I use a variable, final code looks like this, quite primitive, but mission accomplished.

`Flight.objects.filter(airlines__icontains='"' + self.object.code + '"')`

I was thinking that I would need some clever annotation with json.loads and got blocked.

JSONField is perfect, but not in SQLite.

If there is nothing smarter this solution is the best working. Thanks.

Comment: You should also be able to use string interpolation to short the concatenation. `'"%s"' % self.object.code` or with a newer Python version `f'"{self.object.code}"'`

Comment: Agree:) `f'"{self.object.code}"'` will be nicer

Answer (score 0):

On`django==^4.2.7`

```
Flight.objects.filter(airlines_codes__contains='"XX"')
```

Will fail with:

```
NotSupportedError: contains lookup is not supported on this database backend.
```

Because meaning of `contains` for JSON is different and [not supported](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#containment-and-key-lookups) for SQLite.
Still, on DB level JSON is actually text field(for SQLite), so you can filter it as text like:

```
Flight.objects.filter(airlines_codes__icontains='"XX"')
Flight.objects.filter(airlines_codes__regex='"XX"')
```

Other string/text operators should work too.